# CFG for language l

Tags: automata

please solve this question.thanks

Consider the language L expressed by (a+b)*a defined over Σ = {a, b}. Draw FA and construct the CFG corresponding to the language L.

Comment: Why..?  Just "thanks" is not enough to show your respect. Consider at least stating your own ideas please.

Answer (score 3):

i am new here this is why i don't know how to post or where to write.sorry i bother you but i just want to match my answer because i was not sure about my answer.[image]

thank you for answer.

Comment: The language L contains strings that end with "a", but with your grammar you don't describe this.. You could modify your grammar as followed:
$$S \rightarrow Aa$$ 
$$A \rightarrow aA|bA| \varnothing $$
So the word that is accepted contains a sequence of $a$ and $b$ that is created by $A$ and it ends with $a$.
As regards the DFA you have to describe which is the initial state and which the final state.

Answer (score 2):

A context free grammar corresponding to the language $L$  is:
$$S \to aS|bS|a$$

Comment: The grammar is correct. But it is not context free. It is regular, since the language it produces is regular.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Question:Consider the language L expressed by (a+b)*a defined over Σ = {a, b}. Draw FA and construct the CFG corresponding to the language L.

Solution:
(a+b)*a